# How to specify a permission as an access argument?

Tags: 7, routes, users

As I understand for a menu access argument I must specify a permission.

So, let say there is a permission for "Profile: Create new content" that is enabled for authenticated users, and I would like to use this as my menu access check.

This is how I put it in my menu callback?

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['play'] = array(
    'title' => 'Play',
    'page callback' => 'play',
    'access arguments' => array('Profile: Create new content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}
```

This does not work though, so how do I get the permission name used by the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on Drupal 6 but I doubt it has changed.

`access arguments` returns `true` if the user has the permission specified in the array, however, it does not make sure to create that permission if it doesn't exist. If you want to use a module specific permission you need to define it using [hook_permission](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) ([hook_perm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_perm/6) for D6). If there already exists a permission that will suit you needs you can simply call that instead, though.

Comment: Thanks, would you know how I find out the internal permission name? "Profile: Create new content" seems to be just a title presented to users, but I guess, this would be "create profile"?

Comment: The second answer in [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2764/how-can-i-find-out-a-list-of-available-string-values-for-user-accessstring-fu) mentions you can extract the internal name from the checkbox value but I can't test that. I am not entirely sure how hiding the name is an improvement.