# Revoke flag access to node author

Tags: 7, flags

I have a workflow system for my nodes, where one of the states is *Disabled*. There are some flags on those nodes as well; I'd like to to revoke access to flags to the node author when the workflow state is changed to *Disabled*.

I'm looking for any solution, contributed modules or custom modules, or just a combination of modules.

I'm not sure if [`hook_flag_access()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21flag%21flag.api.php/function/hook_flag_access/7) is relevant here or not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need custom module, you can try this code

```
/**
 * Check status of node
 * @param $nid
 * @param $fid
 * @return $result
 * if node have status disable return array()
 * if node have status active return NUll
 */
function check_workflow_status($nid, $fid){
  $result = db_select('flagging', 'fg')
    ->fields('fg', array('entity_id'))
    ->condition('entity_id', $nid, '=')
    ->condition('fid', $fid, '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
  return $result;
}

/**
 * Implement hook_flag_access()
 *
 */
function YOURMODULE_flag_access($flag, $entity_id, $action, $account) {
  // Change flag id with your flag's ID
  // You can dpm($flag) to see flag id of status node.
  $result = check_workflow_status($entity_id, 1);
  if (!empty($result)) {
    // You need check special use have permission use flag status
    if (user_access('flag node_status'))
      return TRUE;
    else
      // Deny access to all other flags of the node. 
      return FALSE;

  }
}
```

You can get string in user_access() at [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2764/how-can-i-find-out-a-list-of-available-string-values-for-user-accessstring-f).

Answer (score 1):

`hook_flag_access` and `hook_flag_multiple_access()` do seem to be the way to go. You will need to write a small custom module for that, which you can read more from [here](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7).

An example implementation is below:

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_flag_access($flag, $entity_id, $action, $account) {
  if ($flag->name == 'NAME' && $flag->entity_type == 'node') {// Change flag name with your flag's machine name.
    $node = node_load($entity_id);
    if ($node && $node->uid == $account->uid) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}

function MYMODULE_flag_access_multiple($flag, $entity_ids, $account) {
  if ($flag->name == 'NAME' && $flag->entity_type == 'node') { // Change flag name with your flag's machine name.
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($entity_ids);
    foreach ($nodes as &$node) {
      $node = $node->uid == $account->uid ? FALSE : NULL;
    }
    return $nodes;
  }
  return array();
}
```

You will need to change "`MYMODULE`" with a module name of your choice, and use the same name and save it as `MYMODULE.module`. Accompany with the `MYMODULE.info`, drop in a folder and activate the module. Above is a sample code for you to start with the module. It checks if the Flag's entity type is `node`. If it's `node`, the relevant node(s) will be loaded, and the user ID will be matched against the provided account's user ID. If they match, it returns `FALSE`, indicating access should be denied. It does not explicitly return `TRUE`, to allow the basic Flag access checks and potential other modules to determine the access.